# Challenged to get ServiceStack self-hosted F# example that works on Windows, working on Docker

Tags: f#, servicestack, docker

I created ServiceStack F# projects using Visual Studio 2013 and ServiceStackVS. I then created a "ServiceStack Self Hosted Empty" project using F#. It works.

However, I'm unable to get the project working after 'containerizing' it with Docker and attempting to run it under boot2docker. I have a tried-and-tested boot2docker in VirtualBox configuration running on the Windows machine. SSH'ing into boot2docker and using shared folders to access the Windows file system from within boot2docker. The Dockerfile builds successfully:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mono:3.10

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy install unzip socat

ADD . /var/www/
WORKDIR /var/www/

RUN nuget install SelfHost03/SelfHost03/packages.config -o packages
RUN xbuild SelfHost03.sln

EXPOSE 8080

CMD /usr/bin/socat -s EXEC:"mono SelfHost03/SelfHost03/bin/Debug/SelfHost03.exe",ignoreeof -,ignoreeof
```

also tried:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["mono","SelfHost03/SelfHost03/bin/Debug/SelfHost03.exe"]
```

But, when I try to run the container, I receive the following:

`ServiceStack SelfHost listening at http://localhost:8080`

Unhandled Exception:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_shell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x0
0000] in :0
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x
00000] in :0
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0
  at SelfHost03.Main.main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in :0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_shell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x0
0000] in :0
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x
00000] in :0
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0
  at SelfHost03.Main.main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 1):

It took some time which was a result of my lack of familiarity with F# but, the problem arises with the addition/inclusion of:

```
Process.Start("http://localhost:8080/") |> ignore
```

Recreating the C# project using the update templates includes the equivalent:

```
Process.Start("http://localhost:8080/");
```

After removing these statements, the projects will continue to run on Windows and the derived Docker images/containers will work too.